# GWT multi-module application

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, project-organization, multi-module

I am a GWT beginner, thinking about developing a management software and deploy it on AppEngine.

In my mind there's a "tabbed" user interface.

Tab1= sales; Tab2= invoices; Tab3= stock ... and so on.

I just completed the Stockwatcher tutorial and it's very cool, but now I was wondering on **how to organize my code**.

I mean, is making a gwt module for each tab a nice idea? For example, I want to load the interface for the 'invoices' tab only when I select that tab. Even if my idea about multimodule is wrong, can you tell me how to avoid having all my code in a "Stockwatcher" class. E.g. i read about composite, but I can't understand.

*Hoping you understand my doubts*. Thank you all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you haven't done yet anything with GWT before or haven't had much experience do not bother yourself with questions how to organize the code. Just make it. Create the user interface and the backing code. Have your application running and then go back and think about the things that could be improved. Look for the code duplication, read few articles on refactoring and try to apply. First you need to create something, feel the joy of creation and form a foundation for further improvements.

Comment: And to add to this: just start with one module, and look at some other larger GWT example projects (as advise from someone who does have experience with GWT;-)

Comment: where can I find one of those projects? anyway... nice suggestion, but I can't mark it as an answer, because I asked you how to split my code units in a 'tabbed' application